# Concatenating two Linked Lists using operator overloading C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, linked-list, operator-overloading

I want to concatenate two link lists using operator overloading. I have been trying for the past few hours but no result.

I am trying to create a separate function for concatenating which I would later use in operator overloading. Here's what I have so far.

**List Definition**

```
struct Node
{
    int info;
    Node* link;
};

class LinkList
{
public:
    Node* head;
    LinkList()
    {
      head = NULL;
    }
 
    void Append(int num);
    void Insert(int num, int position);
    void Print();
    void Delete(int position);
    void concatenate(LinkList list1, LinkList list2);
};
```

**Append function**

```
void LinkList::Append(int num) // Creates a new node
{
    Node* newNode = new Node();
      
    newNode->info = num;
    newNode->link = NULL; 
      
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
        
    else
    {
        Node* temp = head;
        while(temp->link != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->link;
        }
            
    temp->link = newNode;
    }    
}
```

**Concatenation function**

```
void concatenate(LinkList list1, LinkList list2)
{
    LinkList list3;
    
    Node* ptr1 = list1.head;
    Node* ptr2 = list2.head;
    while(ptr1->link!=NULL)
    {
        list3.Append(ptr1->info);
        ptr1 = ptr1->link;
    }
    while(ptr2->link!=NULL)
    {
        list3.Append(ptr2->info);
        ptr2 = ptr2->link;
    }
    list3.Print();
}
```

I am getting [Error] id returned 1 exit status. Could you please help me rectify it? (I would really appreciate it if someone can implement it directly as part of operator overloading)

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please add the error message to your post.

Comment: `concatenate(LinkList list1, LinkList list2);` Do you really need three linked lists for this operation?

Comment: At least one problem you have is in the `while` conditions. Use `while (ptr1)` and `while(ptr2)` instead of what you've written.

Comment: `void LinkList::Append` `void concatenate`one of these things is not like the other.

Answer (score 0):

Use in concatenate function `LinkList&` instead of `LinkList` or implement copy constructor in class

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for taking your time and answering... Here's the solution:

```
LinkList LinkList::operator+(const LinkList& list2)
{
    LinkList list3;
    
    Node* ptr1 = head;
    Node* ptr2 = list2.head;
    
    while(ptr1!=NULL)
    {
        list3.Append(ptr1->info);
        ptr1 = ptr1->link;
    }
    while(ptr2!=NULL)
    {
        list3.Append(ptr2->info);
        ptr2 = ptr2->link;
    }
    list3.Print();
}
```